# Adding Facebook Like button to fan page

Tags: html, facebook

i have a facebook page and i cannot insert the button facebook like. i tried to put an iframe code and it works in a simple site. but in the facebook page dosn't work....why????

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=http://example.com"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it is very difficult to work out what you are asking.  Be specific, post code samples where necessary.  Tell us what you have tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Hey, take a day to read the faq, kthx.

Answer (score 1):

Use [THIS LINK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) for generating the "Like" button you need. This is the official button generator supplied by Facebook.

Comment: i cannot do it with xfbml. and with iframe doesn't work. could i do it with FBML????

Comment: Not very familiar with FBML, but in iframe you can activate and use XFBML.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can try the like box:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert `iframe` on landing page that is the one you have specified in application settings from developer section. You can only insert `iframe` in inner pages.

For example, [I have created this fan page](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=120196931351044&v=app_120196931351044) and it was not allowed to use iframe on landing page, so we made a splash screen and used the iframes all around in inner pages.